# MYSQL Optimizing recurring expressions?

Tags: mysql

Does the Optimizer evaluate the avergae only one time, or two times?

```
SELECT AVG(col1), 1/AVG(col1) FROM table
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about the optimizer, but `EXPLAIN SELECT AVG(col1), 1/AVG(col1) FROM table` returns a single table scan.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about it. Even if mySqueal computes it twice, it will make only one pass over the data as most aggregates are computed in one pass - and it's reading in the data that takes the time, so you want that to happen just once.